# Missing data while scraping the web

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am a new Python user and have been trying to scrape data from the [food network website](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/sandra-lee/a-big-decadent-hot-dog-recipe.html).

[image]

When I use requests and beautiful soup, this section is totally empty. What do I do to read the rating data into Python.

I tried to use selenium
and I get the following error.  I did add the driver location to the PATH variable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proposal_fn.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __in
it__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x0348B710>
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Comment: It can be loaded by JavaScript, so when you get the HTML code you done have the value, try to save the HTML value you are obtaining into a file.html and inspect it

Comment: If you need to read javascript produced html content, you may want to try out selenium webdriver.